# Why statechart is not transitioning to the next state in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a population of 1000 people. I have defined a statechart for the agent. But when I run the model, the state does not transition to the next stage. What is the problem here?

I have added image for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the details of the rate transition, it's impossible to tell from these pictures alone

Comment: as per @mczandrea, this is caused by the rate transition below PotentialUser. Either it is set to 0 or its time unit is not aligned with your model time unit